# pyspark: find number of tweets that contain a word/hashtag

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I'm trying to analyse a JSON file that contains data from the Twitter API. 
I would like to find how many times a hashtag or specific word appears in my dataset. I can get a list of most common tweets using:

```
 print(df.groupby('text').count().sort(desc('count')).show())
```

So I know, for example, that Liverpool is a word definitely in the data.

I would simply like to find how many times the word "Liverpool" appears in my dataset, is this possible? Thanks

I use Spark version 1.6.0.

Columns are named as

```
['_corrupt_record', 'contributors', 'coordinates', 'created_at', 'delete', 
 'entities', 'favorite_count', 'favorited', 'filter_level', 'geo', 'id', 
 'id_str', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'in_reply_to_status_id', 
 'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 
 'lang', 'place', 'possibly_sensitive', 'retweet_count', 'retweeted', 
 'retweeted_status', 'scopes', 'source', 'text', 'truncated', 'user', 
 'withheld_in_countries']
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? Are you using spark 2.0+? Do you already have the data in a dataframe? What are your columns?

Comment: @flyingmeatball Yes, sorry. I'm using Spark version 1.6.0. columns are ['_corrupt_record', 'contributors', 'coordinates', 'created_at', 'delete', 'entities', 'favorite_count', 'favorited', 'filter_level', 'geo', 'id', 'id_str', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'in_reply_to_status_id', 'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'lang', 'place', 'possibly_sensitive', 'retweet_count', 'retweeted', 'retweeted_status', 'scopes', 'source', 'text', 'truncated', 'user', 'withheld_in_countries']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this works in 1.6, I use 2.1, but I'd do something similar to this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.where(col('text').like("%Liverpool%")).count()
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed  to use like rather than isin, but you pointed me in the right direction    df.where(col('text').like("%Liverpool%")).count()

Comment: Tweaked comment above

Comment: @MelesMeles, can you mark the solution as accepted? It's good for the community when they want to look at the solution :)